Orthogonal orthornomal bases imply pair-orthogonal vectors
While self-studying linear algebra i started thinking about following problem: Let's say that $A, B \in \mathbb{C}_{n\times n}$ are orthogonal in a Frobenius sense orthonormal bases of complex vector space. Let $a_i, b_i$ represent a i-th vector in bases $A, B$. From Frobenius orthgonoality we have
$$
\text{Tr}(A^H B) = \sum_i \langle a_i, b_i \rangle = 0
$$
Question: In the described scenario does it imply that $\langle a_i, b_i \rangle = 0$?
In general that does not mean that each $\langle a_i, b_i \rangle = 0$, but I wonder that in this particular scenario this might be the case, yet I am not sure how to progress.
I know that (because $A, B$ are both orthonormal spaces), they only differ by a unitary transformation $U$, that is for $B = UA$, hence $b_i = Ua_i$. This transformation $U$ itself would be traceless, because $0 = \text{Tr}(A^HB) = \text{tr}(A^H UA) = \text{Tr}(AA^H U) = \text{Tr}(U)$.
My intuition is that we at least should have $\text{Re}(\langle a_i, b_i \rangle) \leq 0$.
Could you please tell me if my intuition is right (and why) or wrong?

To simplify the analysis assume $\def\R{\mathbb{R}}A,B \in \R^{n \times n}$ so that the Frobenius orthogonality condition can be written as,
$$
\def\C{\mathbb{C}}
{{A}_i}^j {B^i}_j =0
$$
(the proof is identical for $\def\C{\mathbb{C}}A,B \in \C^{n \times n}$ but requires the derivation of four derivatives instead of one).
Therefore$\def\qty#1{\left( #1 \right)}$,
$$
{{A}_i}^j d {{B^i}_j} + d{{{A}_i}^j}{{B^i}_j}
= {{A}_i}^j \delta^i_k \delta^l_j d {{B^k}_l}
+ {B^i}_j \delta_{iq} \delta^{jr} d{A^q}_r =0
$$
and,
$$
{A_k}^l d {{B^k}_l} =- {B_q}^r d{A^q}_r
$$
Since ${B^k}_l={U^r}_l {A^k}_r$,
$$
d{B^k}_l = {U^r}_l d{A^k}_r =  {U^r}_l \delta^k_q  d{A^q}_r
$$
we have,
$$
{A_k}^l {U^r}_l \delta^k_q  d{A^q}_r = - {B_q}^r d{A^q}_r
$$
and so,
$$
{A_q}^l {U^r}_l = - {B_q}^r
$$
which can be written as,
$$A^T U = -B^T \iff -B=U^TA$$
Since $B=UA$ we must have $0=(U+U^T)A$. This is only possible if $U^T=-U$ i.e. $U$ is skew-symmetric. We know that if $U$ is skew-symmetric then for any vector $x \in \R^n$, $x^TUx=0$. Since $b_i=Ua_i$ we have,
$$
a_i^T b_i = a_i^T U a_i =0, \quad \text{for all $i$}
$$
